# how to create a simple task with one or two console commands in conemu?

Tags: command-line, conemu

So what I want to is just simply when conemu open, I want open two page and one page does this:

```
cd c:/mydir/
```

then do a

```
ls (in mac) or dir (in pc)
```

I just can't understand their default man page, seems no where shows a way to add a tab to run one or two lines of commands...unless I missed it!

Would anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: What can't you understand? IMHO docs are not due to describe "how to use ampersand", are they?

Comment: @Maximus .... ok, Lets say if I just want to run one command line command, I can't see a example that does it.... I am pretty new to conemu, and getting familiar with its task system, which I think is where I suppose to be adding such task when conemu starts?

Comment: Actually I found this post, helped me understand it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802815/conemu-commands-in-task

Answer (score 0):

so to add a task that do cd we can create a new tasks and then put in there:

```
-cur_console:d:C:\
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/TableOfContents.html) contains all required information, each page has "Suggest better edit" at the bottom, but almost nobody cares...